# Select parent object from key in JSON file with Javascript

Tags: node.js, json, express, object

I have a file `brands.JSON` with:

```
{
  "Apple": {
    "ceo": "Steve Jobs",
     "os": "OSX"
  },
  "Microsoft": {
    "ceo": "Bill Gates",
     "os": "Windows"
  }
}
```

In app.js from the node server:

```
app.get('/pages/:brandId', (req, res) => {
  let requestedBrand = req.params.pageId;

  console.log(requestedBrand) // might return "OSX" but I want it to become "Apple"

  let brands = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/views/data/brands.json'));

  res.render('pages/brand', {
    brand: brands[requestedBrand]
  });
})
```

If I click on a link with `'/pages/OSX'`, I want the `requestedBrand` to become `"Apple"`. Same thing if the url asks for `Bill Gates`, I need to select `Microsoft`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the values of the `brands` object, `.find` the one whose object has a value matching the `requestedBrand`, and if it exists, render the object:

```
app.get('/pages/:brandId', (req, res) => {
  let requestedBrand = req.params.pageId;

  console.log(requestedBrand) // might return "OSX" but I want it to become "Apple"

  let brands = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/views/data/brands.json'));
  const obj = Object.values(brands).find(brand => Object.values(brand).includes(requestedBrand));
  if (obj) {
    res.render('pages/brand', {
      brand: obj
    });
  } else {
    // no object found
  }
})
```

Live snippet:

```js
const brands = {
  "Apple": {
    "ceo": "Steve Jobs",
     "os": "OSX"
  },
  "Microsoft": {
    "ceo": "Bill Gates",
     "os": "Windows"
  }
};
const requestedBrand = prompt('Brand?');
const obj = Object.values(brands).find(brand => Object.values(brand).includes(requestedBrand));
if (obj) {
  console.log(obj);
} else {
  console.log('no match');
}
```

This only gives you the object for the brand, because it looks like that's all you want for your `brand: brands[requestedBrand]` - it seems you don't *actually* need the key associated with it. If you *do* need the key, iterate over the `Object.entries` instead of the `Object.values`:

```js
const brands = {
  "Apple": {
    "ceo": "Steve Jobs",
     "os": "OSX"
  },
  "Microsoft": {
    "ceo": "Bill Gates",
     "os": "Windows"
  }
};
const requestedBrand = prompt('Brand?');
const entry = Object.entries(brands).find(([, brand]) => Object.values(brand).includes(requestedBrand));
if (entry) {
  // entry[1] is the object
  console.log(entry[0], entry[1]);
} else {
  console.log('no match');
}
```

Might want to do a case-insensitive search too:

```
const lowerBrand = requestedBrand;
const entry = Object.entries(brands).find(([, brand]) => (
  Object.values(brand).map(str => str.toLowerCase()).includes(lowerBrand)
));
```